# Coded UI - Launching browser as a different user - Text input failure

Tags: impersonation, coded-ui-tests

I have set up a coded ui test where text gets entered into an html text input field. Works perfectly fine when I launch the browser via BrowserWindow.Launch(url).

When I launch the browser as a different user via ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(psi), everything works fine, except of entering that text. When the line "this._control.Text = sText" gets hit in SetText() of CUITe_HtmlEdit, I can see that each letter of the text gets written 3 times into the input field, before the coded ui fails with the following message:

PlaybackFailureException: Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value "r"' on the control.

Obviously, CUITe can write the text into the control, but is not aware that it has done it. I have also tried using the recording and editing UI map option (i.e. not using CUITe), and the problem is the same, hence not a CUITe issue. All other controls work fine (buttons, links, dropdowns).

Any clues anyone?

Here is the code that launches the browser as a different user:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UserName = userName,
    Password = pwSecure,
    Domain = "mydomain",
    FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe",
    Arguments = url,
    LoadUserProfile = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

    ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(psi);
```

I'm using IE9 for this, and the url (ProcessStartInfo.Arguments property) is `http://localhost:81/` (site hosted on local IIS 7.5).

Thanks,
Rudi

Comment: So I guess you still got no solution for this? I've got almost the same problem, one letter gets entered 3 times, even though I'm starting the browser with BrowserWindow.Launch(). It just doesn't happen all the time, just out of the blue sometimes, randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had same problem with my share point application, here is how I got rid of it, Instead of:

```
edit.Text="SomeContent";
```

try this out:

```
Mouse.Click(edit) 
Keyboard.SendKeys("SomeContent") //and then use  to enter values else you can use 
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("YourContent")
```